# checking multiple SQL tables for null values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL script that has queries multiple tables searching for a value but its only to check the next table if the first table returns a null value.
I'm using the case statements, checking IS NULL THEN etc - see below.
There has to be a simpler way to do this?

```
CASE
    WHEN
        CASE
            WHEN
                CASE    
                    WHEN
                        SELECT accountcode from a238 where reference='xyz'
                    IS NULL THEN
                        SELECT accountcode from a241 where reference='xyz'
                    ELSE
                        SELECT accountcode from a238 where reference='xyz'
                END
            IS NULL THEN
                SELECT accountcode from a240 where reference='xyz'
            ELSE
                CASE    
                    WHEN
                        SELECT accountcode from a238 where reference='xyz'
                    IS NULL THEN
                        SELECT accountcode from a241 where reference='xyz'
                    ELSE
                        SELECT accountcode from a238 where reference='xyz'
                END
        END
    IS NULL THEN
        SELECT accountcode from a239 where reference='xyz'
    ELSE
        CASE
            WHEN
                CASE    
                    WHEN
                        SELECT accountcode from a238 where reference='xyz'
                    IS NULL THEN
                        SELECT accountcode from a241 where reference='xyz'
                    ELSE
                        SELECT accountcode from a238 where reference='xyz'
                END
            IS NULL THEN
                SELECT accountcode from a240 where reference='xyz'
            ELSE
                CASE    
                    WHEN
                        SELECT accountcode from a238 where reference='xyz'
                    IS NULL THEN
                        SELECT accountcode from a241 where reference='xyz'
                    ELSE
                        SELECT accountcode from a238 where reference='xyz'
                END
        END
END
```

This code works, but its a prick to work with and read.
Is there a better solution that someone could direct me too?

cheers

Comment: Please set up a [MCVE] with data. You can outer join all tables and check with a flatter `CASE` logic. But even many tables of same structure suggests a database design problem.

Comment: What SQL technology are you using?

Comment: @Parfait the multiple tables are for region control. Broken into daily edits per state, which get merged at the end of the day.  Speeds up access then accessing the global table with millions of records.

Comment: @PanoKatsourakis underlying tech is mssql

Comment: *Speeds up access then accessing the global table with millions of records.*... have you confirmed this with query plans/benchmarking? A normalized database with appropriate indexing is usually more efficient than joining to other tables. You can even partition if needed. Rows are cheap, columns and tables are expensive.

Comment: @megabytes did my answer help you? If so could you please accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

That query would be a huge pain to deal with if you need to debug or modify something. Credit to Parfait in the comments for his suggestion on the full outer join. In addition you can use `COALESCE()` to replace all of the `CASE` statements.

With the nesting and similar table names there is a chance I missed something, but this is the idea.

```
declare @referenceCode varchar(3) = 'xyz'

select 
    COALESCE(a238.accountcode, a241.accountcode, a240.accountcode, a239.accountcode) as account_code
from a238 
full outer join a241 on a241.reference = @referenceCode
full outer join a240 on a240.reference = @referenceCode
full outer join a239 on a239.reference = @referenceCode
where a238.reference = @referenceCode
```

Comment: i tried your suggested code but i was finding that if there were no entries in the first table 'a238' there would be no further joins done.
you code did give me another idea that i could use unions
select account from a238 where reference = ref union select account from a239 where reference = ref